# Should HTML meta charset be lowercase or uppercase?

Tags: html

Normally `UTF` should be uppercased as it's an abbreviation.
However, attributes in HTML are normally lowercased.

So, should it be: `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` or `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`?
I know both work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The value for charset is case-insensitive.

**From spec.whatwg.org**

> The charset attribute specifies the character encoding used by the document. This is a character encoding declaration. If the attribute is present, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "utf-8".

Link to full document: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-meta-charset

Comment: My vote is for lowercase though.  Sort of like they've moved to with sql.  I think it'll be mostly lowercase preferred in the long-term future.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Ilanco. Do you happen to have the link to that quote?

Comment: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2009/04/08/is-utf-8-case-sensitive-in-xml-declaration/  Seems to be of a guy that goes pretty deep into the topic.

Comment: Ah, I had read that, but it's old and mostly oriented towards XML. Plus he recommends uppercase.

Comment: This may not be relevant, but the general trend in everything (even outside of tech) these days has been to lowercase. HTML tags for example. Even in schools they prefer lowercase now.

Comment: And these school kids correct uppercase to lowercase when HTML is created by IDEs? My WebStorm created HTMLs with uppercased "UTF-8".

Comment: As of May 2022 an example on the [head element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-head-element) states: _"The collection of metadata in a head element can be large or small"_. You can freely choose from and switch between lower and upper case as you like: `<META NAME="APPLICATION-NAME" CONTENT="Demo App">`

Answer (score 18):

**As per the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.charset.html)**:

> A [case-insensitive match](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#case-insensitive) for any character set name for which the IANA [[Character Sets]](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) registry has a *Name* or *Alias* field labeled as “preferred MIME name”; or, if none of the *Alias* fields are so labeled, a [case-insensitive match](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#case-insensitive) for a *Name* field in the registry.

The specification does not specifically provide for a *canonical* case. Previously, I would have suggested you just use `UTF-8` (from the [registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml)), however the world is moving to lowercase and I now prefer `utf-8` as it aligns better with all [your other HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags).