# Is there any benefits to use uppercase (or lowercase) letters with html5 tagnames?

Tags: html, xhtml, tags, uppercase, lowercase

I have searched and have read about this question. Some questions here:
[Uppercase or lowercase doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020961/uppercase-or-lowercase-doctype)
[Should HTML meta charset be lowercase or uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888929/should-html-meta-charset-be-lowercase-or-uppercase)
and elsewhere have discussed it partially (as you can see in these 2 questions).
But what about tag names, and attributes?
I know both uppercase and lowercase are valid, but I want to know if there is benefits using each one?

**update:** the only benefit I have seen is compatibility with xhtml in lowercase way.

Comment: see this to clarify why I asked this question, when there is such a benefit: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5

Answer (score 0):

You should use lowercase letters because they are the 'correct' way of doing things (XHTML). It's basically a standard among everyone so that everything is consistent.

Even if you don't agree with the HTML is XML argument (I certainly do), almost all web developers use lowercase and many will get upset when they are forced to use uppercase letters and it will certainly lead to inconsistencies in your markup and CSS which is not a good thing.

Words formed all in capital letters are actually more difficult to read also without having the varying heights of letters (eg. a, l, p) to give your brain hints so you can skim the text faster.

Comment: There is no XML serialization of HTML5 as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @JalalJaberi: Of course there is. The Programmers question you link to talks about something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

There are no benefits. It's only about readability. Choose the one that suits you.

Fact: Usually, on the Internet, when someone writes text in all uppercase, it means that he is "RUDE".