# Is it bad to use uppercase letters for html tags?

Tags: html, uppercase, lowercase

What is the best practice?

```
 <HTML> or <html>
```

And why we should stick with one particular case?

However all browsers seems to interpret both cases and returns the expected output.

Comment: browsers accept also UglYCAse… just all lowercase and nothing to discuss anymore.

Comment: Why not just all UglYCAse ?

Comment: I think it's a matter of opinion here. Personally I find lowercase easier to read.

Comment: it is a personal choice but I haven't come across any webpage will UPPERCASE html tags.

Comment: @dystroy: yes, it is a matter of opinion because it makes no difference, but the point is that the OP didn't know that; a large part of the question here is whether it actually does make a difference or not.

Comment: @h-rai Markdown will generate upper case letters for example.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The lower-case "requirement" is a legacy of xHTML, which explicitly required it.

Plain old HTML on the other hand does not follow the rigid struct requirements of XML, and does not therefore have the fixed requirement for use of case.

However developers have tended to stick with lower case as a convention anyway, mainly on the grounds that it's a lot easier to read when you're working on it, and easier to type. But it is only a convention; there's nothing forcing it. If you have existing code with upper case tags, they will work, and there's nothing stopping you continuing to write your tags that way.

One other thing to be aware of though: In all browsers, when the browser loads the HTML document and parses it, it converts it into a DOM (Document object model). If you then use the browser's built-in developer tools to inspect the site, when you view the DOM, all elements in the DOM will be shown as lower case, regardless of how they were written in the actual source code.

For this reason, if you stick with lower case, you'll find it easier to work with the developer tools, because the code you see in the DOM view will be more consistent with the source code you've written.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do an equals compare on the tagName property of the DOM element, you must remember to do it in UPPER case.

Comment: Also, depending on the webserver you use, it might convert the tags to lowercase on their way to the client, for the same reason as browser built-in tools do.

Comment: Reminder that HTML5 supports XML syntax fully but optionally. For those of us using XML-related tooling, we must be aware that XML is case-sensitive. Some folks use all-lowercase as a practice to avoid accidental case-mismatch errors.

Answer (score 30):

The only relevant parts of specifications say:

- HTML tag and attribute names are case insensitive.
- XHTML tag and attribute names are case sensitive and must be lower case

Stuff that isn't mentioned in any standard:

- Lower case is generally considered easier to read
- Lower case is most common (and what people are used to working with)
- Holding down the shift key or toggling CAPS LOCK all the time is a pain

Answer (score 6):

## Front-end frameworks and libraries may rely on the lowercase convention

The other answers are correct, but another reason to write lowercase HTML (possibly more important than "stick to conventions") is that some front-end frameworks/libraries will rely on this lowercase convention to distinguish between HTML and user-defined components or templates (that typically start with an uppercase letter). [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/), and [Astro](https://astro.build/) are some examples of this, as seen below.

This means that if you are working with a front-end framework it may be impossible to write your HTML tags with uppercase letters. If you are not working with a front-end framework, it may be much harder to use a one in the future if you use uppercase letters in your HTML.

### Examples:

#### [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
> built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'`
> or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a
> capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and
> correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

#### [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/docs#Tags)

> A lowercase tag, like , denotes a regular HTML element. A capitalised tag, such as `<Widget>` or `<Namespace.Widget>`, indicates a component.

#### [Astro](https://docs.astro.build/core-concepts/astro-components#component-imports)

> Note that an Astro component **MUST** begin with an uppercase letter. Astro will use this to distinguish between native HTML elements (`form`, `input`, etc.) and your custom Astro components.

Answer (score 5):

Probably very minor, and I have no evidence to back it up, but I bet using lowercase tags would very marginally improve gzip/deflate compressibility of the page, since most text is also likely to be lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to use one particular case, to prevent confusion. But using upper or lower case does not change a thing.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer lowercase, because that is what is used by the HTML 5.2 specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/introduction.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html

The HTML 4.0 specification shows HTML tags in uppercase, but the specification itself uses lowercase tags in its HTML code:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html

Java's javax.swing.text.html.Html.Tag class uses lowercase (even though the Java constants are in uppercase, as is consistent with Java's naming conventions).

Go's godoc tool uses lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Basically HTML is case insensitive. you can use lower case or upper case when entering HTML tags or HTML tag attributes but with XHTML lower case is required. In preparation for future upgrades, use lower case HTML tags and HTML tag attributes