# aurelia, es6 and classname case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, aurelia

I'm studying custom components in aurealia and come accross strange behaviour which nature I don't understand. Consider this:

component:
xxxaaa.html

```
<template>
    <div>xxxxxx</div>
</template>
```

xxxaaa.js:

```
export class Xxxaaa {}
```

app.html:

```
<template>
    <import from='./xxxaaa'></import>
    <div>
        <xxxaaa/>
    </div>
</template>
```

this works as expected, xxxxxx is shown. Then, camelcaseing component:

xxxAaa.html:
 content not changed, only filename

xxxAaa.js:

```
export class XxxAaa {}
```

app.html:

```
<template>
    <import from='./xxxAaa'></import>
    <div>
        <xxxAaa/>
    </div>
</template>
```

nothing is shown, but log dosen't contain any errors, only:

INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started
index.js:26 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for dist/app.html ["dist/xxxAaa"]
index.js:26 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for dist/xxxAaa.html []

Thus the first question, why is it so?

UPDATE: This looks to me like either bug in aurelia (it fails to properly report wrongly made custom elt) or major gap in my understanding of how it actually works. Could you please either confirm it's a bug or explain why aurelia silently ignores my element.

Then, rolling back to first, working state and after changing xxxaaa.js to

```
export class xxxaaa {}
```

console log error:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at execute._classCallCheck (http://localhost:9090/dist/xxxaaa.js:9:108)
    at xxxaaa (http://localhost:9090/dist/xxxaaa.js:12:9)
    at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/dependency-injection@0.4.5/container.js:362:27)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/dependency-injection@0.4.5/container.js:142:52)
    at Container.get [as superGet] (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/dependency-injection@0.4.5/container.js:238:32)
    at Container.elementContainerGet [as get] (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.14/view-factory.js:27:17)
    at CustomElement.create (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.14/custom-element.js:136:80)
    at applyInstructions (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.14/view-factory.js:79:33)
    at ViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.14/view-factory.js:172:17)
    at CustomElement.create (http://localhost:9090/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.14/custom-element.js:141:58)
```

Thus comes the second question - what causes this case sensivity? Is it es6, babel or aurelia?

UPDATE: I'd expect here complains from aurelia that it can't find class but it looks like it picks up wrongly named class and tries to use it. The exception itself is quite murky (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/887, https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/700) but do I understand it correctly that it's again a case of poor error reporting from aurelia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aurelia never sees the camelcased markup because the DOM lower-cases the element and attribute names.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19808671/725866) answer for more information.  Here's an excerpt:

> One other thing to be aware of though: In all browsers, when the browser loads the HTML document and parses it, it converts it into a DOM (Document object model). If you then use the browser's built-in developer tools to inspect the site, when you view the DOM, all elements in the DOM will be shown as lower case, regardless of how they were written in the actual source code.

Another approach:

If you name your class `XxxAaaCustomElement` [Aurelia conventions will kick in](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/custom-element.js#L24-L28) and you'll be able to use `<xxx-aaa></xxx-aaa>` in your markup.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to CustomElement, it's really makes it easier. But I still want to make sure I understand the cases fully. I updated the questions to make them more explicit, could you please take a look?