# POST HTML textarea to PHP Variable without input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Having spent more than two days seeking an answer to this quandary, I'm now posting the question direct.
There have been numerous hints and snippets of answers but nothing which definitively resolve the issue I'm facing, hence the post.

I have the following script with one specific issue, 
I'm unable to pass content of a textarea to another php file which is activated via an href which triggers a dynamic form to be created.

The notion is to:
Have a Variable: "comment"
Have a textarea delivered via a form that accepts text and stores it into the variable "comment".
When the user then clicks the `<a href="hsl:logcall?...` hyperlink, this is passed across to the updatedb.updatetxt table in the database.
Can get set text to pass but not a variable based on textarea info...

Here's the html/php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<TABLE CELLSPACING="10">
<TR>
    <TD>
    <TABLE>
    <TR>
    <TD>
    <p>
    <b>Please use the below to start capturing your Call Description:</b>
    <form method="POST">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" cols="45"></textarea>
    </form>
    </TD>
    <TR>
    <TD>

<?php
$comment = $_POST[comment]; // Variable who accept your data from textarea
// You don't need to use variables, but if you starter, easier to understand.
    // Do something with your arrived data... 
// Stupid, but for short explanation... for example echo it...
echo $comment;
?>
    <a href="hsl:editrecord?formmode=edit&table=userdb&key=<?=$userdb_keysearch;?>"><img src="img/icons/call_update.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Edit Details</a>

    <a href="hsl:logcall?userdb.keysearch=<?=$userdb_keysearch;?>&updatedb.updatetxt=<?=($_POST[comment]);?>"><img src="img/icons/call_detail.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Log New Call</a>

    <a href="hsl:printme"><img src="img/icons/call_print.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Print This Page</a>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the original unedited code

```
<a href="hsl:editrecord?formmode=edit&table=userdb&key=<?=$userdb_keysearch;?>">
<im‌​g src="img/icons/call_update.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Edit Details</a> 
<a href="hsl:logcall?userdb.keysearch=<?=$userdb_keysearch;?>">
<img src="img/icons/call_detail.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Log New Call</a> 
<a href="hsl:printme"><img src="img/icons/call_print.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Print This Page</a>
```

Comment: html is not your friend or? pls check your html-code

Comment: Nobody writes HTML in uppercase since 1999...

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: `stripslashes($data);` can break your data unless you have magic quotes turned on (which you shouldn't).

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use a validator: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: @D4V1D You can write your HTML in uppercase but above all you need to valid your code !

Comment: @MrSo [I still tend to use lowercase letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19808575/2788131).

Comment: Yes ok I know that : But it's only a convention... And i think it's not the subject here :)

Comment: This was the original unedited php code:
'code' <a href="hsl:editrecord?formmode=edit&table=userdb&key=<?=$userdb_keysearch;?>"><img src="img/icons/call_update.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Edit Details</a>
<a href="hsl:logcall?userdb.keysearch=<?=$userdb_keysearch;?>"><img src="img/icons/call_detail.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Log New Call</a>
<a href="hsl:printme"><img src="img/icons/call_print.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0" />Print This Page</a> 'code'

Comment: apologies, can't seem to get the coding recognised proprerly :-(

Comment: Please edit the question to add more code, dont put it in a comment. I have added it to your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the form before the browser will take the data from it and put it in a request where PHP can read it.

You have no submit button (nor do you have any JavaScript that would submit the form). Add one.

Comment: The submit needs to be triggered when the user clicks the '<a href="hsl:logcall?...' part of the output.

Comment: @RaymondPaxton — Then you need to make that a submit button and have the URL you want to load be generated by PHP and issued as an HTTP redirect. Alternatively, rewrite the entire thing in client side JavaScript. You can't use server side code without making an new request to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons:

- You haven't a `<form>`
- You haven't a `<input type="submit">` to submit the form
- You are writing text into `<tr></tr>` wich is totally incorrect.
- Your textarea needs to pass the comment too like this: `<textarea....><?=$comment;?></textarea>`
- There's many security problems that you need to repair: escape harmfull code of the strings for example

Good luck

Comment: Also $_POST[comment] <- probably needs the comment part quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Marcos
The <form> appears on line 38 (followed by _"method="post"_
The table construction was copied from an online table example code
The security issues are null as this is internal only
I know I ned to pass teh comment...that's why I'm posting as cannot get this to work - the passing is occuring under the **<a href="hsl:logcall?...**