# HTML padding-left not working for div

Tags: html, css, android-webview

I'm creating a very simple webpage. It has a div tag with a single paragraph containing some text.

```
<HTML>
 <Head>....</Head>
 <Body> 
 <div id="titlebox">
 <p>First Heading</p>
 </div>
 </Body>
```

Here is a the CSS style for the div:

```
div#titlebox {background-color:#f2f2f2; 
              padding-top:2px;
              padding-bottom:2px;
              padding-left:2px;  }
```

Snippet:

```css
div#titlebox {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<Head>....</Head>

<Body>
  <div id="titlebox">
    <p>First Heading</p>
  </div>
</Body>

</HTML>
```

The text appears correctly, background color is also fine, but regarding padding, only padding-top is applied while padding bottom and left are ignored. Any suggestions on what is wrong with this code? By the way I am new to HTML. I googled the issue, there was point regarding float, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I copy-pasted the code.. it does in fact work :)) are you sure that you're just not noticing the changes due to the small margins that you have set?

Comment: yes code is working, if it is not on your end than reason is something else

Comment: @Acrux Yes the small value ( 2px ) was the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine :)) I simply made padding bigger to make it more obvious

```css
div#titlebox {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<HTML>


<Head>....</Head>

<Body>
  <div id="titlebox">
    <p>First Heading</p>
  </div>
</Body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Yes, that indeed was the problem. What confused me was that  at 2px value padding-top and bottom were quite large and visible, but padding left wasn't. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution you can try without using css

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div align="left" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
 <p>First Heading</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Hello I wouldn't criticise you I see you are a beginner, that would just dis encourage you but normal syntax, html,head,body written in simple letters to avoid confusion of reading your own code later

follow this url:

[Is it bad to use uppercase letters for html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Your left and bottom padding is working but you probably can't see it because 2px is really small. Change it to 20px or something and you should see the padding.

Handy tool - if you are using Chrome, you can right-click on the element you want to inspect and select the Inspect tool to see all your padding and margins on a diagram.

--note-- depending on which browser you are using, there will be some default styles/padding/margin applied to certain elements already, in this case your paragraph tag already have some top and bottom padding

Comment: yes this was the reason, as I said in the comment to the answer above. thanks for the inspect element trick. By the way can you till me which unit should I use instead of px if I want to use this html page in my android app in a webview?? dp doesn't  seem to work in webview.