# How to click on Yes and cancel button in window

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am facing an issue where in I am not able to identify yes and cancel button on a window.
Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Screenshot
[Image of a Popup Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4sQy.jpg)

Here is the javascript code

```js
<A onclick="javascript:SaveAndNavigate('CloseApplication','',false)" id=PageHeader_CloseApplication class=PageHeaderLink href="#">Close VSS</A>
```

Here is my code

```
try
    {
        WebElement window=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Close VSS')]"));
        window.click();
        Set<String> windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
        for(String windowss:windows)
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowss);
            String source=driver.getPageSource();
            if(source.contains("Do you want to close the application" ))
                    {
            WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("PageHeader_CloseApplication"));
            JavascriptExecutor JS=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            JS.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
                    }

        }


    }
    catch(NoSuchWindowException e)
    {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this popup in new window?? And in which line of provided code have you problem???need to share if any exception occurred, And need to share popup HTML as well.

Comment: Yes its a new popup window.I have given the image screenshot.
The problem is to identify and click on Yes/No button.

Comment: Could you share that popup HTML as well..:)

Comment: And could you share what is the problem to identify button means share exception as well...:)

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with the anchor link.

It should be

```
<a></a>
```

but not

```
<A></A>
```

Comment: HTML tags and attribute names are case insensitive. Refer to the answer by @Quentin from this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags