# Inserting XML using JQuery changes attributes to lower case

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to insert some html via jquery (1.6.1) using the following line:

`$('#myElem').html(htmlString);`

This `htmlString` variable contains some HTML with attributes contained, for example:

`<div myCustomAttribute="1">...</div>`

When the XML is inserted, examining the elements on the page, I see the following:

`<div mycustomattribute="1">...</div>`

Is there a reason for this? How can I avoid this from happening?

[Click here to see an example of this in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLnyc6hm/27/)

Edit: Unfortunately I can't really change it to use the `data` attributes (as it should be) because I am working on an existing system that has a huge amount of javascript that is checking for this particular attribute name. For various reasons, renaming the attribute would also cause existing data to break.

Comment: HTML is case insensitive, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle please? There is no reason for this to happen

Comment: @Budyn I have added a fiddle.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19808671/8108407 The element inspector makes anything lower case.

Comment: HTML is case insensitive, and you can use any case to get value from javascript.

Comment: @MikeBaxter about your question "Get name of current project configuration" it is possible ... ask it again to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.

The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.

The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or server-side database queries).

The data-* attributes consist of two parts:

**The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"**
The attribute value can be any string
Note: Custom attributes prefixed with "data-" will be completely ignored by the user agent. Refer  [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)!

Answer (score 0):

All the attributes on your elements are changed to lower case as jQuery is parsing them and re-writing them in lower case (as valid html).

HTML specification has a specific tag for [custom attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Prepend your attribute with `data-`:

```
<div data-myCustomAttribute="1">...</div>
```

When working with jQuery - it wont modify the case of the `data-*` attribute.

You can read and write to the attribute with jQuery:

```
$('div').data('myCustomAttribute') // == 1
```

Or

```
$('div').data('myCustomAttribute', 2)
// Which will create
<div data-myCustomAttribute="2">...</div>
```

You can also use CSS to select the elements by their `data-` attributes and apply styles to them:

```
[data-myCustomAttribute='1'] {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

See here for more [css](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) examples.

Answer (score 0):

All the attributes on your elements are changed to lower case as jQuery is parsing them and re-writing them in lower case (as valid html). You can get value from is actual also no matter what case is.

```js
function insertHtml() {
 var someHtml = '<div myAttr="1">Inspect me to see my attribute</div>';
  $('#target').html(someHtml);
}

$('#getValue').on('click', function(){
 alert($('#target div').attr('myattr'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='insertHtml()'>
Insert HTML
</button>

<div id='target'>
  
</div>

<button id="getValue">
getvalue
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the following javascript, which appends to an element in a case-sensitive manner:

```
var newElem = $.parseXML(data).documentElement;
myObj.append(newElem);
```