# How to add fonts to classes

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Hey can anyone fill me in on how to add fonts to HTML classes? I was watching a tutorial and that part skipped and I'm confused exactly what he did. There was a box class with different elements in it and he was trying to add font styling before it skipped.

This is the HTML and CSS, excluding the `<head>` and `<body>` tags:

```css
.body {
  Background-color: red;
}

.box {
  Width: 174px;
  Height: 250px;
  Background: yellow;
  Width: 25px Padding:20px;
}

.true {
  Background-color: brown;
}

.true2 {
  Background-color: green
}
```

```html
<Div class="box true"> this is an example</Div>
<Div class="box true2> parenthesis</Div>
```

Comment: Please make sure your HTML and CSS is syntactically correct. You’ve got a missing semicolon before `Padding` and a missing quote for your `class` attribute.

Comment: Do you mean any font (answered in any decent documentation - here's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)), or a custom font (answered in [Using custom fonts using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144000))?

Comment: It's common practice to keep your HTML elements lowercase, so your `Div`s would be come `div`s. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags#answer-19808671)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) styling in your classes:

Example:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add custom fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

And then just juse `font-family: myFirstFont;` whenever you need it.