# Make input field and button that move/resize together but do not move another elements

Tags: html, css, button, input, resize

I have these text field and button for search and some other button:

```css
button {
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.search {}

.search:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table
}

.search input {
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 160px;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 42px;
  border: 2px solid #404040;
  background: #FFDFBF;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.search input:focus {
  width: 512px;
}

.search button {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -44px;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="search">
  <INPUT type=text name="q">
  <BUTTON></BUTTON>
</DIV>
<BUTTON>Some other button...</BUTTON>
<BUTTON>Some other button 2...</BUTTON>
```

I need other buttons to be placed right of the text field when it is in the normal state but NOT to move when the text field is resized (they must be behind the field).

But the search button must remain bound to the right side of the text field.

Who knows how to do this?

Comment: You'll want to position your search field absolute then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the content in div `position: relative;`, and make other button position `absolute` with left value width of input + spacing, and also give negative `z-index` to go behind the search input.

Something like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.other-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}

button {
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.search {}

.search:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table
}

.search input {
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 160px;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 42px;
  border: 2px solid #404040;
  background: #FFDFBF;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.search input:focus {
  width: 512px;
}

.search button {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="search">
    <input type=text name="q">
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <div class="other-btn">
    <button>Some other button...</button>
    <button>Some other button...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Also use lowercase for html tags, it's a good practice. Refer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808514/is-it-bad-to-use-uppercase-letters-for-html-tags) for more info.

Comment: How to be if all the construction is not aligned left? And what to do with multiple other buttons, set class "other-btn" to them all? What if their width is unknown?

Comment: wrap the other btns in another parent `div` and make this parent `absolute`, let me update the answer, I see you have updated the question also, left position should be provided otherwise default value is `0`

Comment: I cannot make the `div` right to the search field absolute because I do not know the absolute offset since all the line is not aligned left. When I did so with centered line, the search was centered whereas the buttons were placed absolute. How to fix this?

Comment: to send the other btns to go beyond the expanded input you need ‘absolute’, for dynamic width you can use js logic to check width & add left position

Comment: Very sadly. I have now set container to relative and both search and other-btn to absolute, and the line is now aligned left. But maybe it is even better for my case. Thanks!

Comment: @NickolasEtyuhibosecyu sometimes we don't get what exactly we are looking for but point is to get creative ideas to solve the problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.search {
    display: inline-block;
}
```